# UpdateModelFromDatabaseException when trying to add a table to Entity Framework model

Tags: visual-studio-2008, entity-framework

I'm running into a weird issue with Entity Framework in .NET 3.5 SP1 within Visual Studio 2008.  I created a database with a few tables in SQL Server and then created the associated .edmx Entity Framework model and had no issues.  I then created a new table in the database that has a foreign key to an existing table and needed to be added to the .edmx.  So I opened the .edmx in Visual Studio and in the models right-clicked and chose "Update Model From Database...".  I saw the new table in the "add" tab, so I checked it and clicked finish.  However I get an error message with the following text:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
An exception of type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Model.Commands.UpdateModelFromDatabaseException' occurred while attempting to update from the database. The exception message is: 'Cannot update from the database. Cannot resolve the Name Target for ScalarProperty 'ID <==> CustomerID'.'.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

For reference, here's the tables seem to be the most pertinent to the error.  `CustomerPreferences` already exists in the .edmx.  `Diets` is the table that was added afterwards and trying to add to the .edmx.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomerPreferences](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdatedTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdatedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Diets](
    [ID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdatedTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdatedBy] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Diets]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Diets_CustomerPreferences] FOREIGN KEY([CustomerID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[CustomerPreferences] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Diets] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Diets_CustomerPreferences]
GO
```

This seems like a fairly common use case, so I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue wound up being from trying to put the objects in an `Entities` namespace.  Apparently it's a reserved keyword that conflicts with the tools.